# TinyMCE icons not showing due to browser security setting

Tags: security, tinymce, webfonts

I am working on a web project that is used by security minded people. Some of them have turned off webfonts and due to this the icons such as undo, redo, bulleted list ext.ext. are not showing up.

That being said, the first thing i did was attempted to load the fonts required in my main css file before the TinyMCE code was loaded.

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family: 'tinymce';

    src: url('fonts/tinymce.eot');
    src: url('fonts/tinymce.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/tinymce.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/tinymce.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/tinymce.svg') format('svg');
}
```

However this has still not resolved my issues. Is there any guidance anyone can give me as to a way to get these icons to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since webfonts are blocked I ended up having to change to a different editor ckeditor. here is there site http://ckeditor.com/demo.